# How can I prevent getting duplicates with this UNION select (Or a different method)

Tags: sql-server, database, duplicates, union

I am trying to get a certain set of results with a UNION SELECT, and I am having trouble figuring out how to limit my results accordingly. Essentially I have objects that I am returning and displaying in the form of several of their attributes. One of those attributes is a comment that can be made on the object. Some have comments on them, and some do not. I want to display all that have comments as well as all that do not have comments. The problem I am running into: My first SELECT is returning all of the instances with comments just fine, but my second SELECT which is meant to return the instances without comments, not only does that, but also returns a duplicate instance of the previous, but without a comment. So in the end I have all instances where there is no comment, and if there is a comment, I get in instance with the comment and a duplicate but without the comment. I have pasted my code below, but if you feel there is a better way of doing this other than using a union select, your enlightenment is much appreciated.

Some Background: In my DB, I have my main table of 'Deals' and a Deal can have many comments, and I am using the DealID with a marker to tell if that Comment is active or not.

My Stored Procedure:

```
 @Dealership nvarchar(50)

AS

    SELECT DealDate,
    DateReceived,
    Bounced,
    StockNumber,
    LocationName,
    CustomerName,
    Comment 
FROM
    tVehicleDeal,  
    tDealerships, 
    tInternalLocations,
    tVehicleComments,
    tCustomer
WHERE 
(tVehicleDeal.DealershipID = tDealerships.DealershipID) 
AND (tDealerships.DealershipName LIKE '%'+@Dealership+'%')
AND tVehicleDeal.InternalLocationID = tInternalLocations.InternalLocationID
AND tVehicleDeal.DealID = tVehicleComments.DealID
AND tVehicleDeal.CustomerID = tCustomer.CustomerID
AND NOT tInternalLocations.LocationName = 'Down Deal' 
AND tVehicleDeal.Titled IS NULL
AND tVehicleDeal.Archived = 0 

    UNION SELECT DealDate,
    DateReceived,
    Bounced,
    StockNumber,
    LocationName,
    CustomerName,
    NULL
FROM

    tVehicleDeal,  
    tDealerships, 
    tInternalLocations,
    tCustomer

WHERE 
(tVehicleDeal.DealershipID = tDealerships.DealershipID) 
AND (tDealerships.DealershipName LIKE '%'+@Dealership+'%')
AND tVehicleDeal.InternalLocationID = tInternalLocations.InternalLocationID
AND tVehicleDeal.CustomerID = tCustomer.CustomerID
AND NOT tInternalLocations.LocationName = 'Down Deal' 
AND tVehicleDeal.Titled IS NULL
AND tVehicleDeal.Archived = 0 

ORDER BY [DealDate] ASC
```

-Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to read up on the SQL-92 Join syntax.  You need to use an `Outer Join` to the comments table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read up on the [SQL-92 Join syntax](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/oracle-sql-programming/basic-sql-join-semantics/). You need to use an Outer Join to the comments table.

try this:

```
SELECT DealDate, DateReceived, Bounced, StockNumber, 
   LocationName, CustomerName, Comment 
FROM tVehicleDeal vd
   Join tDealerships d 
      On d.DealershipID = vd.DealershipID
        And d.DealershipName LIKE '%'+@Dealership+'%'
   Join tInternalLocations il 
      On il.InternalLocationID = vd.InternalLocationID
        And il.LocationName <> 'Down Deal' 
   Join tCustomer cu 
      On cu.CustomerID = vd.CustomerID
   Left Join tVehicleComments c 
      On c.DealID = vd.DealId
WHERE vd.Titled Is Null
   And vd.Archived = 0
```

Comment: It seems that this worked exactly how I wanted it to. Now I shall research to understand why it worked! Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. Upon further review I have noticed some duplicates only on deals with multiple comments. in my tVehicleComments table I have a CurrentComment marker that is either 1 or 0 (1 meaning it is the current comment) Wanting to display only the current comment, I added AND c.CurrentComment = 1 but not only did I continue to see three instances of a Deal (even though only one comment had currentcomment set to 1) but it also prevented me from seeing any non commented deals.

Comment: @LeoStotch,  It works because when you use an `Left Outer Join`, or a `Right Outer Join`  (the word `Outer` is implied by saying `Left` or `Right`, and is optional), for each row in the table on the "inner" side, if the table on the "outer" side has no records to join to, the output row is still generated (it would be omitted for a regular inner join), and the fields from the outer side are all populated with null values.

Comment: If I want to add an 'and' clause for a field that is in the tVehicleDeal table, similar to the And d.DealershipName LIKE '%'+Dealership+'%' line in the code that you posted above, where would the proper placement be? The line would be something like:   'And vd.DealNumber LIKE '%'+ DealNum +'%'

Comment: Any additional predicate on a table which is only in an inner join (as `tVehicleDeal` is) can be placed either as an additional join condition (in the `On` clause for that join), or in the `Where` clause.  Which is better is purely esthetic (how you view the logic of the query).

Comment: I tried putting it in the Where clause after all of my joins, (In place of vd.Titled Is Null above) I specified WHERE vd.DealNumber = '%207310%' I also tried using LIKE, but I am still returning all DealNumbers instead of just the one. Does this match with one of the placements that you suggested?

Comment: If you only want one deal number, then replace the Where clause with   `Where vd.DealNumber = '207310'`  The percentage signs are wildcard place-holders.

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns many results, I will try playing around with the placement a bit more but there must be something wrong elsewhere in my code

Comment: If you put what I said in the where clause it may return many rows, but it cannot return data for any other DealNumbers than the one specified. If there are many rows, than you must have many rows in onme of the other tables for that single deal number.

Answer (score 1):

If the results on both sides aren't EXACTLY the same you'll get both.  Since you have the NULL in place of Comment in the second query, the result for that row is different from the result in the first query and thus you get both results.

One way to fix it would be to add a

```
AND Comment IS NULL
```

to the second query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately AND Comment IS NULL caused the SP to not return Deals that don't have comments at all, and duplicates still exist for deals that have multiple comments, as an instance is being displayed per comment

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your problem then.  If that's the case you need to convert to joins.  There are already some other answers that should help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest that you

- Use `JOIN` syntax instead of the `WHERE`
- Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `tVehicleComments`

and this way you should be able to avoid the repeated query with the `UNION` entirely, e.g.

**Edit**
If you potentially have more than one comment per `vehicledeal`, you can restrict the output to just one of them by grouping by the remainder of columns and applying an appropriate Aggregation function to the comment, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    DealDate,
    DateReceived,
    Bounced,
    StockNumber,
    LocationName,
    CustomerName,
    MIN(Comment) AS FirstComment
FROM
    tVehicleDeal 
    INNER JOIN tDealerships
      ON tVehicleDeal.DealershipID = tDealerships.DealershipID
    INNER JOIN tInternalLocations,
      ON tVehicleDeal.InternalLocationID = tInternalLocations.InternalLocationID, 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tVehicleComments 
      ON tVehicleDeal.DealID = tVehicleComments.DealID
    INNER JOIN tCustomer 
      ON tVehicleDeal.CustomerID = tCustomer.CustomerID
WHERE 
  tDealerships.DealershipName LIKE '%'+@Dealership+'%'
  AND NOT tInternalLocations.LocationName = 'Down Deal' 
  AND tVehicleDeal.Titled IS NULL
  AND tVehicleDeal.Archived = 0 
GROUP BY
    DealDate,
    DateReceived,
    Bounced,
    StockNumber,
    LocationName,
    CustomerName;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Using your suggestion is so far the closest I have gotten to my desired result! I will have to do some research on LEFT OUTER JOIN to understand how it works. I am now able to see all of the deals with comments as well as all of the deals without comments, but it seems that duplicates are still being shown for deals that have multiple comments, one instance of the deal per comment.

Comment: I've updated with an aggregate to restrict to just one (arbitrary) comment.